# How can I solve: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in React Js for my sign in form

Tags: reactjs

I humbly need your help to resolve the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED issue whenever I try to sign in an already signed up user using my chat app that am building in react Js and stream. It will be good if you jus show me what I might have missed by editing my below code. Thank you in advance!

```
//This is my code//
const { connect } = require('getstream');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const StreamChat = require('stream-chat').StreamChat;
const crypto = require('crypto');

require('dotenv').config();

const api_key = process.env.STREAM_API_KEY;
const api_secret = process.env.STREAM_API_SECRET;
const app_id = process.env.STREAM_APP_ID;

const signup = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { fullName, username, password, phoneNumber } = req.body;

        const userId = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');

        const serverClient = connect(api_key, api_secret, app_id);

        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

        const token = serverClient.createUserToken(userId);

        res.status(200).json({ token, fullName, username, userId, hashedPassword, phoneNumber });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);

        res.status(500).json({ message: error });
    }
};

const login = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { username, password } = req.body;
        
        const serverClient = connect(api_key, api_secret, app_id);
        const client = StreamChat.getInstance(api_key, api_secret);

        const { users } = await client.queryUsers({ name: username });

        if(!users.length) return res.status(400).json({ message: 'User not found' });

        const success = await bcrypt.compare(password, users[0].hashedPassword);

        const token = serverClient.createUserToken(users[0].id);

        if(success) {
            res.status(200).json({ token, fullName: users[0].fullName, username, userId: users[0].id});
        } else {
            res.status(500).json({ message: 'Incorrect password' });
        }
    } catch (error) {ads
        console.log(error);

        res.status(500).json({ message: error });
    }
};

module.exports = { signup, login }
```

Comment: Are you getting this error in console?

Comment: yes Akshay am getting that eror in my console

Comment: Can you share full error stack and the code where you start the server?